# When I loop through rows and conditionally change one column, the loop executes really slowly. How can I make the operation faster?

Tags: r

Here I'm checking to see in each row whether the first column element is equal to "060075". If not, I want to change the element to "Other". When I run the code on the first 100 rows, it takes 10s. I need to run it on 6.5 million rows. **How can I make it faster?**

```
for (i in 1:nrow(full_data_2)){
    if (full_data_2[i, 1] != "06075") {
      full_data_2[i, 1] <- "Other"
    }
  }
```

Here is str(full_data_2)

```
data.frame':    6497651 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ fips     : chr  "Other" "Other" "Other" "Other" ...
 $ SCC      : chr  "10100401" "10100404" "10100501" "10200401" ...
 $ Pollutant: chr  "PM25-PRI" "PM25-PRI" "PM25-PRI" "PM25-PRI" ...
 $ Emissions: num  15.714 234.178 0.128 2.036 0.388 ...
 $ type     : chr  "POINT" "POINT" "POINT" "POINT" ...
 $ year     : int  1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 ..
```

.

Comment: Please show us `str(full_data_2)` and also paste `dput(head(full_data_2))` into your question as an edit.  This is likely an issue of data type: you have some type of numeric and when you make it "Other" is is now character, slowing you down.  Check your timing by setting to `NA` instead of "Other".

Comment: 6 M lines will be slow no matter what you do!  Try @gcering answer and probably someone will suggest the best `data.table` approach (not my area).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take advantage of vector operations to speed things up. Operating on element sometimes requires making copies of data frame. The easiest way to change your code is

```
full_data_2[,1] <- ifelse(full_data_2[,1]=="06075", "Other", full_data_2[,1])
```

data.table is another alternative which operates on list and usually faster than data frame.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works

```
# assume df is your data frame
library(data.table)
setDT(df) # convert df to data table
setkey(df, col_1) # key the column of interest. Assume it's col_1
df["06075", col_1 := "Other"]  # Assign "Other" to col_1 if element is "06075"
df
```

Comment: This is pretty much what `data.table` was made to do.